# Combining two statements: I have no information. They are coming to my flat.

Tags: sentence-construction

Management of the building called me and told me that they couldn't manage to visit my flat that day. I didn't know that they were about to visit me. So I just wanted to tell my landlord their planned visit. So I was to write one of these two sentences below. I couldn't decide which one is the best way to describe.

> I have no information that they are coming to my flat
>
> I have no information about them coming to my flat

Answer (score -1):

I think what you are trying to express is

> I don't know whether they're coming to my flat.

This means that they might come to your flat or they might not. You're uncertain which of those two things may happen.

You could also say

> I don't know when they're coming to my flat.
>   if you know they are coming but are uncertain about the time.

If you want to express both in sentence, you have to use two phrases.
Written:

> I do not know whether they are coming to my flat, and if they do come when they are coming.

Spoken:

> I don't know if they're coming to my flat or if they come when they're coming.

If someone is really pestering you about this potential visit, you could say

> I don't know if they're coming. I don't know when they're coming. I really don't have any information about this.

But that would be very emphatic and even a little rude.